# How to use the binary output of a Cargo project as the input of another one?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In order to reduce the executable size of a Rust program (called `runtime` in my code), I am trying to compress it and then include it in a second program (called `szl`) that decompresses it and executes it.

I have done that by using a [Cargo build script](https://git.m-labs.hk/M-Labs/artiq-zynq/src/commit/22531b14c0205df2f1c6a8c18535f1e47f2515ea/szl/build.rs#L8) in `szl` that opens the output binary from `runtime`, compresses it, and then generates a file that is ready for use by `include_bytes!`.

The issue with this approach is the dependencies are not handled properly. For example, Cargo may try to build `szl` before `runtime` (and fail), and when the source code of `runtime` is modified, `szl` is not rebuilt.

Is there a way to tell Cargo that `szl` depends on the binary from `runtime` (and transitively on the source code of `runtime`), or should I use another approach such as an external Makefile?

Comment: Maybe some sample of code or a configuration will be useful to see what you are already doing.

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly your use case, you might get it to work with the [links manifest key](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#the-links-manifest-key). It would allow you to express a dependency between the two programs and you can pass more information with `DEP_FOO_KEY` variables.

Before you go to such drastic measures, it might be worth it to try other known strategies for reducing rust binary size (such as calling strip, remove debug symbols, LTO, panic=abort) etc.

Comment: No, that does not work. As far as I can tell, `links` and the other native library import features of Rust assume that the library is already present in the system, installed e.g. by the Linux distribution's package manager.

Comment: if you have control over both projects, couldn't you just declare a 'fake' dependency in `scl` to depend on `runtime` so it gets built before?

Comment: That does not work because `runtime` is an application and not a library.